# which package has / creates terminfo files?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I was trying the new xubuntu 20.04 beta today, and wanted to report a bug concerning the terminfo files (the terminfo for xterm-256color has an escape sequence that older vte/terminals don't recognize, so when ssh'ing in to 20.04 from 18.04, vi becomes unusable, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1872896).

However, I can't find the package the terminfo files come from:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3503 Feb 26 08:14 /usr/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
# dpkg -S /usr/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color 
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
# apt-file search /usr/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color 
(no output at all)
#
```

`apt list installed | grep terminfo` doesn't list anything either.

I assumed the files get generated from some source during install, but that doesn't match the date (Feb 26 is way older than my install), and the file itself isn't a link to some other file, checking the link count.

So, which package is actually responsible for terminfo files, and how do I find out?

Comment: Thank you for helping to test Ubuntu *focal fossa*.  I'll suggest #ubuntu-quality via IRC or telegram, or #ubuntu+1 (IRC which is also suitable for support requests on *focal fossa*.  Sorry I don't know the package name so answer.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).   *I realize you're trying to help make Ubuntu better, for which I thank you, but consider UF, IRC or Telegram with development channels*

Comment: FWIW `ncurses-base` provides `/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color`. Perhaps your `dpkg -S` search is coming up empty because the `/usr/lib` version is a symlink? See https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/ncurses-base/filelist

Comment: Actually `/lib` is a symlink to `/usr/lib` - that's why `realpath` and `namei -m` didn't find any symlinks when checking the `/usr/lib/` path. So yes, `ncurses-base` provides the file in `/lib`, and the symlink redirects it to `/usr/lib`.

Comment: `dpkg -S /usr/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color` will show which package provides the file.